# Change direction of animation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this cloud effect http://solidgiant.com/2011/02/awesome-cloud-effect/ but i want to change the direction of the cloud movement. i want them to move right to left, Can anyone help me with this

i am done with the change in direction as told by Nishchay Sharma, but still one problem is there, the clouds doesnt run in loop.. they just gte stuck when they reach left side :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In clouds.css, change:

```
#cloud
{
    ...
    left: 5%;
    ...
}
```

to

```
#cloud
{
    ...
    left: 80%;
    ...
}
```

and in clouds.js change

```
$("#cloud")
        .animate(
            {
                left: $("#sky").width()
            },
            cloudMoved ? 180000 : 150000,
            "linear",
            function()
            {
                $(this)
                    .css("left", parseInt($(this).css("width")))
                cloudMoved = true;
                cloudMove();
            }
        )
```

to

```
$("#cloud")
        .animate(
            {
                left: 0
            },
            cloudMoved ? 180000 : 150000,
            "linear",
            function()
            {
                $(this)
                    .css("left", parseInt($(this).css("width")))
                cloudMoved = true;
                cloudMove();
            }
        )
```

Do the same to `$('#cloud2')` and `$('#cloud3')`. (Change `$(..).animate('left')` to 0.)

**Further Addtion**
To get the clouds back on the other corner after they complete their animation.
For each `cloudMove()`, `cloud2Move()` and `cloud3Move()`:

Change

```
.animate(
            {
                left: 0
            },
            cloud3Moved ? 400000 : 150000,
            "linear",
            function()
            {
                $(this)
                    .css("left", -parseInt($(this).css("width")))
                cloud3Moved = true;
                cloud3Move();
            }
        )
```

to

```
.animate(
            {
                left: "-"+$("#cloud").width()+"px"
            },
            cloud3Moved ? 400000 : 150000,
            "linear",
            function()
            {
                $(this)
                    .css("left", parseInt($(window).width()+'px'))
                cloud3Moved = true;
                cloud3Move();
            }
        )
```

Note: Don't forget to change the `left:` option according to the cloud id.

Answer (score 0):

In your cloud.js change the cloudMove() function to -

```
function cloudMove()
{
    if (!cloudMoved)
    {
        $("#cloud")
            .css("left", $("#cloud").offset().left)
    }

    $("#cloud")
        .animate(
            {
                left: -($("#cloud").width())
            },
            cloudMoved ? 180000 : 10000,
            "linear",
            function()
            {
                $(this)
                    .css("left", $("#sky").width() - $("#cloud").width())
                cloudMoved = true;
                cloudMove();
            }
        )
}
```

Change the timers to your liking!

The other two clouds are just copies - you can do the same with them

Comment: i am done with that.... when the clouds go to the end of right side... they should come again from the right side.... currently the clouds just get stuck at left side...

Comment: With my code I did not have any issue of cloud getting stuck. Hope you already fixed it. " when the clouds go to the end of right side" - I think you mean to say " when the clouds go to the end of left side" as your clouds were moving from right to left.

Answer (score -1):

change (remove "-" sign)

```
.css("left", -parseInt($(this).css("width")))
```

to

```
.css("left", parseInt($(this).css("width")))
```